# Is there a function to only change value of cells that have numbers in them in a column, or a function to avoid empty cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was looking for a function to check the cells in a column and if they have a number in them, it would set their value to 0 or possibly avoid blank cells

`function reset() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('I17:I118').setValue('0')

}`

That's the current code I have, but that changes every single cell in the range to a 0, but I want it to only change cells that have a number in them to a 0

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function resetCellThatContainANumber() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange('I17:I118');
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(!isNaN(vA[i][0])) {
      vA[i][0]=0;
    } 
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```

My Example Before and After running function

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the code you gave me also resets every cell in the range to a 0

Comment: I just tested it again and it only resets numbers to zero.

Comment: Hmm, I accidentally didn't copy a bit of, that's why
Thanks for helping me